# How to install Python and Python packages on Azure VM?

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm playing with a Windows Azure Virtual Machine, and I want to run and debug some Python scripts on it via the remote. How do I install Python, IDEs, and the necessary packages on it? Do I just go about installing it like how I do on my home computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install the Python, IDEs, and the necessary packages on the **Windows** Azure VM, you can first [RDP to that Windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/connect-logon) then [install Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) or download the Python packages locally then upload to Azure VM. You will download the Python Releases for **Windows** depending on your OS.

Generally, Azure VM works as your local machine, you also could install [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), Select **Python development** on the Workloads page, and then click **Install**.

Answer (score 2):

It's same as how you install packages on your local machine. You can read about Installing Packages on VM from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/python/python-sdk-azure-install)

Mostly you would use pip to install necessary libraries,

```
pip install azure-storage-blob==12.0.0
```